# Javascript DOM,accesing the textnode of the <li>element using nextsibling property

Tags: javascript, html, dom, traversal, nextsibling

```
<body>
    <div id="li-container">
        <ul>
            <li class="hot">item1</li>
            <li id="secLi" class="cool">item2</li>
            <li class="cool">item3</li>
            <li class="cool">item4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var secLi = document.getElementById("secLi");
var sib = secLi.nextSibling;
document.write(sib);

//OR //OR  //OR //OR  //OR //OR  //OR //OR  

var secLi = document.getElementById("secLi");
var sib = secLi.nextSibling;
document.write((sib).textContent);

</script>
</body>
```

I want to get the textnode of the third list(li) item using nextSibling property and write in the document.I know I can use "li.textContent" to access it but I want it this way.

No,I am not looking for "nextElementSibling",I want to acess the "textNode" of "secondli" using "nextSibling" property and that is because if I want to get to the "third li",I must use "nextSibling.nextSibling"twice to get to the "third li".(1)First "nextSibling" is for the "text-node" of the "2nd li" and (2)Second "nextSibling" is for the "3rd li".So I am not able to get the text-node of "2nd li" using "next-sibling" once.

I used text-fixer.com to remove other white-spaces and line breaks even then it dosent work.

Comment: What do you see wrong in second way..you want to get `item3` to be written in document.right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for `nextElementSibling`?

```
var secLi = document.getElementById('secLi');
secLi.nextSibling; // Is a text node.
secLi.nextElementSibling; // Is the <li> you're looking for, so..
secLi.nextElementSibling.textContent; // Gives you "item3"
```

**Update**

To better understand why you want `nextElementSibling` instead of `nextSibling` look at what the parent `<ul>` says its `childNodes` are:

```
secLi.parentElement.childNodes;
// [#text, <li>, #text, <li>, #text, <li>, #text, <li>, #text]
```

You don't want the `nextSibling` because it's just the empty text between list items. You want the next *element* (list item).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling

Comment: what is the difference between "nextSibling" and "nextElementSibling"

Comment: @amguruprasath The difference between `nextSibling`property and `nextElementSibling`, is that nextSibling returns the next sibling node as an element node, a text node or a comment node, while nextElementSibling returns the next sibling node as an element node (ignores text and comment nodes). Src: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp

Comment: Taken straight from the Mozilla docs: "nextElementSibling read-only property returns the **element** immediately following the specified one in its parent's children list." "nextSibling read-only property returns the **node** immediately following the specified one in its parent's childNodes list". So in this case, you want the **element** (`<li>`) because the next **node** is actually a text node.

Comment: `nextSibling` selects the _next_ sibling node. An `elementNode`, `commentNode` or a `textNode`. `nextElementSibling` selects the next `elementNode` sibling that has `nodeType` of `1`.  In your code `nextSibling` selects a `textNode`, this `textNode` contains  line break and other hidden characters that you have used for formatting your markup. If you remove the hidden characters then `nextSibling` selects the same node.

Comment: No I am not looking for nextElementSibling,I want to acess the textNode of second list using nextSibling property and that is because if I want to get to the third list item I must use (nextSibling.nextSibling) to siblings thats text node of second list and its reaching the third list item.So I want to get the textNode

Comment: No. You're still confused. I'll update my response for (hopefully) greater clarity.

Comment: @Vohuman I just used text-fixer.com to remove other white-spaces and line breaks even then it dosent work.I have updated my question.

Comment: @amguruprasath I believe there are still some hidden characters there, it should be like `<li id="secLi" class="cool">item2</li><li class="cool">item3</li>`. You don't have do remove the hidden characters. Just use `nextElementSibling` property or iterate through the `nextSibling`s and filter the first next sibling that has `nodeType` of `1`.

Comment: I dont want the 'nextElementSibling' 's  text node.I want that paticular element's 'nextNode'

Comment: @amguruprasath Now I'm out!

Comment: `secLi.nextSibling; //` Is a text node #text in you updated code(2nd line).Is the #text I am trying to get @ brianvaughn

Comment: It's not the text you're trying to get. That's what I'm saying. It's the empt text between the two list items (e.g. "</li>   <li>"). Just *run the code I've provided* and you'll **see** that it works.

Answer (score 0):

the `textnode` of the `li` element is a `child` of `2nd li` element.
So the code would be 
var sib = secLi.firstChild.textContent;
document.write(sib);

@brianvaughn